# jQuery ancestors using jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to check ancestry using two jQuery objects. They don't have IDs, and are only going to be available as jQuery objects (or DOM nodes if you called `get()`). jQuery's  `is()` only works with expressions, so this code would be ideal but will not work:

```
var someDiv = $('#div');

$('a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).parents().is(someDiv)) {
        alert('boo');
    }
}
```

Just want to see if one element is a child of another and I'd like to avoid stepping back into DOM land if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the index() method to check if an element exists in a list, so would the following work?

```
var someDiv = $('#div');

$('a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).parents().index(someDiv) >= 0) {
        alert('boo');
    }
}
```

From [#index reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index#subject).

Comment: Perfect Gareth, thank you! I'd up-vote you, but my meager 11 reputation score prohibits me from doing so.

Answer (score 10):

Checking for `(this).parents().index(someDiv) >= 0`, as @Gareth suggests, will work just fine.

However, using the [jQuery ancestry plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ancestry) is **way faster / more efficient**.

Comment: Thank you! The ancestry plugin and DOM methods are considerably faster.

Answer (score 1):

Along those lines, parents() optionally accepts a selector itself:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  if ($(this).parents("#div").length) {
    alert('boo');
  }
});
```

Comment: .parents() only accepts the most basic of selectors (i.e. only selectors describing a single element will work - not selectors describing ancetry such as "p strong").

Comment: I simplified my example a bit, so in the actual code I am getting the parent object using stored jQuery references instead of string selectors.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the filter function

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).parents().filter(function() {
       return this == someDiv[0];
    }).each(function() {
       alert('foo');
    })
}
```

I think you may also be able to get away with using jQuery.inArray

```
if ($.inArray( someDiv, $(this).parents() ) ) {
        alert('boo');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you not get the result you want from simply using a CSS selector?

```
$( '#div a' ).click( function() { ... } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var someDiv = $('#div');

$('a').click(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).parents().get(), someDiv.get(0)) {
        alert('boo');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $element = $('a');
while ($element && !$element.is('someDiv')) {
   var $element = $element.parent();
};
```