# Testing objects for ancestor/descendent relationship in JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to come up with a reusable JS or jQuery function that would allow me to test if one object is a DOM descendant of another.

I've seen a model of testing for

```
$b.parents('nodename').length>0
```

Which is fantastic when you only need to check if an element is a child of any node by that name.

But what about a specific node? You can't test

```
$b.parents($a).length>0
```

Because jQuery parents takes a nodename expression as an argument to filter.

As a little background, I'm trying to test if a document click event's target is a child of a specific object. For instance, if the event.target is a child of $b, return true, otherwise, return false. But this function could have other implications later on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [jQuery ancestors using jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245241/jquery-ancestors-using-jquery-objects#245266) I suggested

```
if ($(obj1).parents().index($(obj2)) >= 0) {
    // obj1 is a descendant of obj2
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This one actually allows the passing of an object instead of selector which is fantastic. Thanks again!

Comment: You can pass an unwrapped DOM element to index, so this could be simplified to if ($(obj1).parents().index(obj2) >= 0)

Comment: There's now a $.contains, if you're worried about Node.contains.

Answer (score 22):

```
a.contains(b)
```

This is a pure JavaScript solution using [Node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.contains). The function is inclusive, `a.contains(a)` evaluates to true.

There's an edge case in IE9: if `b` is a text node, `contains` will always return false.

Comment: This is great! It works for me. I always prefer pure JS over frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#foo').filter(function(){

   return $(this).parent().is('#foo-parent');

});
```

So here we are selecting all the foo elements and then filtering only the elements that have the foo-parent as their immediate parent.

If you are looking to find if the any of the ancestors of the current object comply to the rule, then I guess it should be:

```
$('#foo').filter(function(){

   return $(this).parents().is('#foo-parent');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Alexey Lebedev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13588053/6951887) did not work for me, because `Node.contains` is inclusive.

If the **parent element should be distinct from its possible descendant** --that was my use case--, then we need a slightly different solution: we could apply `Node.contains` to the parent's direct descendants using the [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) property:

```js
const sapiens = document.querySelector("#homo-sapiens")

const isSapiensAnAustralopithecusDescendant = [
  ...document.querySelector("#australopithecus").children
].some(child => child?.contains(sapiens))

console.log(isSapiensAnAustralopithecusDescendant) // true
```

```html
<div id="australopithecus">
  <div id="homo-erectus">
    <div id="homo-neanderthalensis"></div>
    <div id="homo-sapiens"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this way, `Node.contains` will compare the possible descendant to the given child and its children.

Another solution could be the [`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method. However, if you use it, keep in mind that you should call it on the possible descendant because **`Element.closest` tells us who the ancestor of an element is**.

Also, the function is inclusive; hence, if you do `document.body.closest("body")`, the result will be `document.body` (`Element.closest` returns the closest element with the given selector or `null`).

If your use case demands that the parent and the possible descendant be different, then we could apply `Element.closest` to the parent of the possible descendant:

```js
const sapiens = document.querySelector("#homo-sapiens");

const isAustralopithecusAnAncestorOfSapiens = sapiens.parentElement.closest("#australopithecus")

console.log(isAustralopithecusAnAncestorOfSapiens != null) // true
```

```html
<div id="australopithecus">
  <div id="homo-erectus">
    <div id="homo-neanderthalensis"></div>
    <div id="homo-sapiens"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```