# jQuery to hide all row classes except 'row2' only when the parent class is viewContainerTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been to [jquery select class inside parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394470/jquery-select-class-inside-parent-div) and [Testing objects for ancestor/descendent relationship in JavaScript or Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287875/testing-objects-for-ancestor-descendent-relationship-in-javascript-or-jquery) and [jQuery wild card character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389005/jquery-wild-card-character) but can't seem to fit the pieces together. Thanks.

```
<div id="viewContainerTop" class="top">
    <div class="row1"></div>
    <div class="row2"></div>
    <div class="row2"></div>
    <div class="row2"></div>
    <div class="row3 first"></div>
    <div class="row3"></div>
    <div class="row3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machting the code you posted (parent has **id** viewContainerTop)

```
$("#viewContainerTop > div:not(.row2)").hide();
```

Matching what you wrote (parent has **class** not id viewContainerTop)

```
$(".viewContainerTop > div:not(.row2)").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks jitter.  I won't update the text in the title making my mistake permanent and your answer logical. :-)

On to the next issue...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719211/jquery-to-hide-all-classes-that-start-with-row-except-row2-only-when-the-pare

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#viewContainerTop > div:not(.row2)").hide();
```