# jQuery to hide all classes that start with 'row' except ‘row2’ only when the parent class is viewContainerTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

A variation of [this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719047/jquery-to-hide-all-row-classes-except-row2-only-when-the-parent-class-is-viewc)

```
<div id="viewContainerTop">
  <div class="row1"></div>
  <div class="NotRow1"></div>
  <div class="row2"></div>
  <div class="row2"></div>
  <div class="row2"></div>
  <div class="row3 first"></div>
  <div class="donthideme"></div>
  <div class="row4"></div>
  <div class="row5"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
$('#viewContainerTop > [class^=row]').not('.row2').hide();
```

The `>` is optional--it excludes matching of any deeper objects that start with `row`.

Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/ohoto) that shows this, too (hit refresh to see the selector dim the desired elements).

Comment: You understood perfectly.  Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding your direct question, but a better approach might be to create another class, say "canhide" and attach it to the divs you want to target. You should not be doing matches on partial class names.

```
<div id="viewContainerTop">
  <div class="canhide row1"></div>
  <div class="NotRow1"></div>
  <div class="row2"></div>
  <div class="row2"></div>
  <div class="row2"></div>
  <div class="canhide row3 first"></div>
  <div class="donthideme"></div>
  <div class="canhide row4"></div>
  <div class="canhide row5"></div>
</div>
```