# jquery 'contains' for DOM elements rather than selectors

Tags: jquery

I want to find out if DOM element a contains DOM element b (that is, if a is an ancestor of b in the DOM tree).  Thus, something like:

```
$(b).closest(a);
```

but where 'a' is a DOM node here, not a selector.

Can jQuery help with that?  All the useful functions I can find take selector strings rather than elements, which doesn't really help if your DOM element is anonymous.

Comment: In the current version of jQuery, `closest()` [does accept](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) DOM nodes as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I failed miserably with searching but a coworker found the answer is already around at [Testing objects for ancestor/descendent relationship in JavaScript or Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287875/testing-objects-for-ancestor-descendent-relationship-in-javascript-or-jquery) but the question was asked in such a different way that I didn't find it:

```
if ($(obj1).parents().index(obj2) >= 0) {
    // obj1 is a descendant of obj2
}
```

Still not as efficient as I'd expect, though ('find all the parents and then check for a match' versus 'step up the tree looking for a match').

There's also 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ancestry, which provides exactly the functions I'm talking about.

Update:

```
if($(obj1).parents.eq(obj2)) { ...
```

also works and is marginally neater.  The parent list is unlikely to be that long so this should be fairly efficient.

Comment: jQuery find() method is more appropriate for this purpose.

Comment: "$(parent).find("... er, what?  If what you have is an unnamed DOM node, then you can't make the selector it requires as an argument, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the docs for [Traversing](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing). I recomend you using:

- [find()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr)  to find descendents of a specific type, maybe starting from document itself
- [parents()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents#expr) to find parents of specific type in the DOM tree starting from an x element

Comment: As I said, ... "where 'a' is a DOM node here, not a selector"

Comment: are you talking about this? https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XBL/XBL_1.0_Reference/Anonymous_Content

Comment: No, I'm talking about a DOM node for which I have a reference but no selector.  To me, it's just a reference.  And it's hard to turn that reference into a selector because it may not have an ID - that is, it's nameless, or anonymous.

Comment: you don't need an ID to identify DOM elements. Traversing function do that in jQuery, and you can access each element in the DOM without being explicitly identified. Actually when you do $(b) you already have a jQuery object wrapped over your DOM object. http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#elements. This means that you can  use this functions without any problems.

Comment: @Elzo: that's absolutely true for the element you're looking under, but - using find() and selectors - I can't find a way to describe the element you're looking for if it doesn't have a name.

Comment: if is part of the DOM has the DOM has a way of identify it, by tag, by name, by id..., as should you.